# Fallback for missing custom tabs with Xamarin and Azure AD B2C

Tags: xamarin, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, chrome-custom-tabs, azure-ad-msal

I followed the sample on [Xamarin Authorization with Azure AD B2C](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/TodoAzureAuthADB2CClientFlow/)

That uses Custom Chrome Tabs (and the Safari equivalent).

I do not find any resources on how to handle the case if no Chrome is installed on the mobile device. I just noticed in emulator, it just raises an error dialog that Chrome must be installed. But I do not want to exclude users from signing in/up that use alternative browsers.

Are there any links/tutorials that cover this (crucial) behavior?

Comment: MSAL  in Android or iOS requires support for Custom Chrome Tabs for displaying authentication prompts. So, you need a emulator with Chrome.

Comment: I know. My emulator has Chrome installed and it works. The question is how to handle a fallback when no Chrome is installed. I don't want to force users to install chrome just to login. Excluding users will result in a lower conversion rate. Or  does nobody else care for those users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSAL now suports a fallback using the embedded browser of Android / iOS:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/msal-net-2-released#you-can-now-leverage-the-embedded-web-browser-in-xamarinios-and-xamarinandroid

> You can now leverage the embedded web browser in Xamarin.iOS and
>   Xamarin.Android
>
> In the previous versions of MSAL.NET, Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS
>   used the System web browser interacting with Chrome tabs. This was
>   great if you wanted to benefit from SSO, but that was not working on
>   some Android phones which device manufacturers did not provide Chrome,
>   or if the end user had disabled Chrome. As an app developer, you can
>   now leverage an embedded browser. To support this, the UIParent class
>   now has a constructor taking a Boolean to specify if you want to
>   choose the embedded browser. It also has a static method,
>   IsSystemWebviewAvailable(), to help you decide if you want to use it.
>   For instance, on Android: bool useSystemBrowser =
>   UIParent.IsSystemWebviewAvailable(); App.UIParent = new
>   UIParent(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context as Activity, !useSystemBrowser);
>
> For more details about this possibility see the article in MSAL's
>   conceptual documentation: https://aka.ms/msal-net-uses-web-browser.
>   Also the web view implementation might change in the future

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a different library such as:

[AppAuth for Android](https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-Android/)

"When a Custom Tabs implementation is provided by a browser on the device (for example by Chrome), Custom Tabs are used for authorization requests. Otherwise, the default browser is used as a fallback."

[AppAuth for iOS](https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-iOS/)

"iOS 9+ uses the in-app browser tab pattern (via SFSafariViewController), and falls back to the system browser (mobile Safari) on earlier versions."

(Note that Microsoft Authentication Library is consistent with [the IETF's Best Current Practice for OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252.txt) that:

"... the best current practice is to perform the OAuth authorization request in an external user agent (typically the browser) rather than an embedded user agent (such as one implemented with web-views)."

Comment: Thanks for the links. But before accepting the answer I will wait if someone has a solution related to Xamarin and Azure AD B2C. Using the above mentioned librariers will result in a completely different handling of authorization.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I've got the same problem using the Microsoft.Identity client - I can't release my Xamarin Android app in the Amazon app store because Chrome isn't available for Amazon Fire tablets.

Comment: No I did not solve it until now. But my App is not near to production, so this is not an urgent topic and I hope it will be resolved until then